# Create object that inherits from base-class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-instances

Maybe this is a bit of a beginner's question but I need some help regarding this issue.

Assume there is a class A that inherits from class B that itself inherits from class C.

Now when class A constructor looks like this everything is fine:

```
A::A(params)
  :B(params)
{
}
```

Next I tried this but it fails:

```
A::A(params)
  :C(params)
{
}
```

Why can't I ignore inheritance from B here - or is there a way to make this possible? Defining A as follows does not work, here compiler complains C is already a base class of A:

```
class A : B, C
```

Comment: "It fails" is not a very good description of the problem. What is the real error you're seeing?

Comment: does B have a non default constructor?

Comment: @Jon, "type 'C' is not a direct or virtual base of 'A'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't I ignore inheritacne from B here - or is there a way to make this possible?

Because classes can only decide how to construct their *direct* subobject. The direct subobject for `A` is `B` and for `B` is `C`. The `B` object needs to be constructed too, you can't bypass it.

The [error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91c45808819f67cb) you got, basically complains about this.

> Defining A as follows does not work, here compiler complains C is already a base class of A: `class A : B,C`

With:

```
class A : B, C
```

you are actually declaring a *private* multiple inheritance. And since you said `B` has already a subobject (inherits from) `C`, the compiler is complaining that inheriting from `C` in `A` is useless.

But please remember to always specify the `private`/`protected`/`public` kind of inheritance so that you avoid confusion. By default the inheritance for `class`es is `private` and for `struct`s is `public`. So the above code corresponds to:

```
class A : private B, private C
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
class C
{
public: C(ParamType param) { ... }
};

class B : public C
{
public: B(ParamType param) : C(param) { ... }
};

class A : public B
{
public: A(ParamType param) : B(param) { ... }
};
```

There is really no other way....

Comment: As Jeffrey said in his comments, when C is a virtual Base class of B, I was able to call constructor of C in Constructor initializer list of A.

Comment: True. Virtual base is a sort of exception. This is complex case. Are you sure you really need this? Read about this first and provide more evidence that you need this.